# Select dropdown not adding CSS first time only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So I'm being cracking my head at this issue for quite some time and I'm stumped as to why the code is behaving as such.

So I'm using the following in my project:

**AngularJS v1.2.22**
**Bootstrap v3.1.1**
**jQuery v1.5**

Scenario:
I have 2 select dropdown's where the values are retrieved from the DB using angular **(working)**, on the UI aspect I have to disable the 2nd dropdown based on the first dropdown's value (selected) also works (used scope.watch), but it fails only on the first time i.e. based on the default values set, it doesn't disable it.

Actual:
On load first time based on the default value the 2nd dropdown should be disabled but its not

Excepted:
It should get disabled

This is what stumps me,
I have got it to work using ng-disabled="dropdown2" and the angular side $scope.dropdown2 = true;

This disables the dropdown but, the CSS doesn't work.

IfI change the above to ng-disabled="{{dropdown2}}" and the angular side $scope.dropdown2 = 'disabled';

Then dropdown doesn't get disabled but, the CSS works.

Code
**AngularJS**

```
$scope.$watch('formItem.dropdown1',function(newValue,oldValue){
        if(newValue.cd==='A' || newValue.cd==='B'){
       //$scope.dropdown2= 'disabled';
        $scope.dropdown2= true;
      $document.find("#eldropdown2").next().addClass('disabled');
        $document.find("#eldropdown2").attr('disabled',true);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-7" >
    <select class="form-control"  id="eldropdown2" ng-model="formItem.dropdown2" ng-options="c.valueForDisplay for c in dropdown2"  ng-disabled="dropdown2" paCombobox></select>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me figure out why AngularJs/Js does this ??

**EDITED**

My colleague helped me fix this issue my adding the following line in the JS

**ANGULAR JS**

```
$scope.dropdown2= true;
$scope.$watch('formItem.dropdown1',function(newValue,oldValue){
        if(newValue.cd==='A' || newValue.cd==='B'){
       $scope.dropdown2= 'disabled';
       // $scope.dropdown2= true;
      $document.find("#eldropdown2").next().addClass('disabled');
        $document.find("#eldropdown2").attr('disabled',true);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-7" >
    <select class="form-control"  id="eldropdown2" ng-model="formItem.dropdown2" ng-options="c.valueForDisplay for c in dropdown2"  ng-disabled="{{dropdown2}}" pa-combobox></select>
</div>
```

Above scope.watch, But how did it work ?? clearly this is a hack right ?? I mean since ng-disabled="{{dropdown2}}" will accept el-value and not boolean value right but how does it work ??

Also upon further investigation I came across this piece of code in the JS side

```
app.directive('paCombobox', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (value) {
        element.selecter('destroy');
            if(scope.disableEle || element.attr('ng-disabled')==='disabled'){
                element.selecter();
                element.selecter('disable');
            }else{
                element.selecter({
                    inputFilter:true
                });
                element.selecter('enable');
            }
        var tabIndex = element[0].tabIndex;
            if(tabIndex != -1){
                element.parent().find('div.selecter')[0].tabIndex = tabIndex;
            }
        });

    };
});
```

Can anyone tell me Why and how this works?? and what is the best practice to follow, clearly the above seems like a hack and it shouldn't work right ??

Answer (score 0):

I have two initial ideas for you to try,

At the end of the $scope.$watch maybe try adding a $scope.$apply()?  It could update the DOM to inform it of the needed css change.

The other idea I would have would be to use an ng-class and query for dropdown2.

```
ng-class="dropdown2?'class for dropdown2 == true':'class for dropdown2 == false'"
```

Comment: tried with ng-class it didn't work....will try with $scope.$apply() and get back to you... any idea as to why it behaves as such ??

Comment: I'm not 100% sure without the full context, but I think ng-class should work.  Just have the select from the first drop-down update a scope variable that will then activate the disabled class.

Comment: I have added all the changes required to recreate the issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the class try to use the attribute `disabled`:

```
<select disabled id="eldropdown2" ng-disabled="dropdown2"></select>
```

And then with angular remove the attribute instead of the class.

Comment: I can do this ...I just wanted to know why it fails ?